# What is the formal definition of " Express the double integral in polar coordinate "?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, multiple-integral

I was reading [Tom Apostol calculus volume 2](https://archive.org/stream/CalculusTomMApostol/Calculus%20vol.%202%20-%20Tom%20M%20Apostol#page/n413/mode/2up)  and came across, the change of variable  for double integral (page 392), the exercise followed by the sections (section 11.28), the very first question of nearly :-

> **"Express the double integral in polar coordinates"**
>
> Now my question is **What is the formal definition of the above statement ?**

Comment: Do a change of variables to polar coordinates. I think more context is needed before I could give a more useful answer. What exactly seems informal about this task?

Comment: I  somewhat , gave the link for the book ,the formal definition of the first question the exercise 11.28 , is my question in short.

Comment: As per the answers of many, I would like to know whether the *question statement* is rigorous or not , or is it just informal question for computation for beginners in the topic ?

Comment: What is a "rigorous" question? I really can't understand what you are asking.

Comment: https://archive.org/stream/CalculusTomMApostol/Calculus%20vol.%202%20-%20Tom%20M%20Apostol#page/n420/mode/1up the first question in exercise 11.28 , is what i am referring.

Comment: questions are statement so they may or may not be logically precise.@saulspatz

Comment: @Bijayan Ray, yes the task is clear in a sense you might call logically precise. What makes you think otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

You presumably have an integral $\int \int f(x,y)\;dx\; dy$ over some region where $x$ and $y$ are Cartesian coordinates.  You are expected to write an equivalent integral $\int \int g(r,\theta) r\; dr\; d\theta$ over the same region with $r, \theta$ being polar coordinates.

Comment: I appreciate your help ( +1 ) but it did not clarify my doubt completely, by polar coordinate I understand nothing more than a change of variable and equivalently coordinate transformation, your  statement seems informal, I would ask for formal statement which is actually what my question all about.

Comment: I would like to know whether the *question statement* is rigorous or not , or is it just informal question for computation for beginners in the topic ?

Comment: It is a description of a task, not a mathematical proof. I would see it in the same way as "add these two numbers".  If I saw it, I would know what I was expected to do, so would see the task as well defined.  The computation I did could be expressed rigorously or not

Answer (score 2):

The statement simply means that you express the variables $x$ and $y$ in terms of $r$ and $\theta$. Any point in the plane can be uniquely expressed by a vector with length $r$ from the origin forming an angle $\theta$ with the positive x-axis in the counterclockwise direction. I have not opened the book you are referencing, but say you are solving the double integral of $1$ over the disk $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$. This integral can be transformed in terms of $r$ and $\theta$ as follows: $$\int\int_D dxdy = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 drd\theta$$ where $D$ is the domain of integration (here the unit disk).

Comment: Note that the in the first exercise you are referencing you are asked to do exactly what I described above, except your domain of integration is a disk with radius a, so the upper limit of the integral wrt. r is a.

Comment: I know what to do and how to solve the problem, but the approach of interpreting the question did not convinced me totally, that is why i posted the question, my question is not what to do ? but why to do? what does that question means formally?

Comment: I appreciate your help ( +1 ) but it did not clarify my doubt completely, any more improvement to make the statements rigorous would be helpful.

Comment: I would like to know whether the *question statement* is rigorous or not , or is it just informal question for computation for beginners in the topic ?

Comment: There is nothing non-rigorous about the question statement. If you feel that the transformation is done in a non-rigorous way (by simply using the sketch of the region to infer limits of integration and adding an r as an area scaling factor) then you could always apply the general formula for a change of variables to obtain the scaling factor and solve for the new limits of integration using $x=rcos\theta$ and $y=rsin\theta$, but using the sketch is strongly advised. You would need the limits in the Cartesian system to do this, ex: $x$ from $-\sqrt{a^2 - y^2}$ to $\sqrt{a^2 - y^2}$ and $y$-1,1